# httpsなしでweb push通知をもらう方法はありますか。

Tags: javascript, http, https, push-notification

自作タイマーをgithub pagesで公開するとプッシュ通知がうまく見えますが、本番環境の80ポートにデプロイするとchromeは通知を受けません。調べてみるとこの機能は信頼性の高いhttpsがいるのです。chromeの設定とかを変えて、httpを信頼して、プッシュ通知をうまく表示させる方法はありますか。

開発環境：github pages
本番環境：centos7 apache
発信コード：

```
function push() {
    Push.create('完成！');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 設定とかを変えて、httpを信頼して、プッシュ通知をうまく表示させる方法

Firefoxでは可能なようです。

MDNのドキュメントを参照すると、

> アプリがプッシュ通知メッセージを受信するために、アプリでサービスワーカーが動作している必要があります。
> [Push API - Web API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Push_API)

> サービスワーカーはセキュリティ上の理由から、 HTTPS 通信でのみ動作します。ネットワークリクエストが改変されると、中間者攻撃を受けるので、人間に広く開かれているのは本当にまずいことです。
> （中略）
> Note: Firefox では、テストのためにサービスワーカーを HTTP (安全ではない) 上で実行することができます。これは、 HTTP による サービスワーカー を有効化 (ツールボックスを開いたとき) オプションを Firefox Devtools 設定メニューでチェックするだけです。
> [サービスワーカー API - Web API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

ということで、FirefoxでHTTPによるサービスワーカーを有効化すると、HTTPでPush APIを利用することが可能かもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変助かりました！